# Overriding parameterized methods in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

Note: I apologise for altering this question, previously I wan't able to express the exact issue I am facing.

Let's say we have an abstract parameterized class `abs`,

```
abstract class abs[T] {
    def getA(): T
}

class ABS[Int] extends abs[T] {
    override def getA(): Int = 4
}
```

gives the following incomprehensible error:

```
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.Int(4)
 required: Int
       override def getA(): Int = 4
                              ^
```

I want to override the method `getA`.

Also an explanation or some helpful link would be really appreciated.

Comment: @m-z: Are you saying that I am writing redundant code? From this example, I just want to learn how this is done.

Comment: It's confusing as to what `getA[T]` is supposed to do generically. It's also more confusing that the type parameter of the method shadows the type parameter of the abstract class.

Comment: @m-z: What does "type parameter of the method shadows the type parameter of the abstract class" mean?

Comment: You can't override the same method twice. What are you actually trying to do? And what m-z is talking about is that the class `abs` has a type parameter `T` and then the method `getA` has another type parameter, but that's also called `T`, which is very confusing.

Comment: @m-z: Here I just want some overridden method to return different value for different type. Here I have taken the example of `Int` and `Char`.

Comment: @Imm: Ok, so if I change `getA` in abstract class `abs` to `def getA[U]: T` so does that resolve shadowing issue? I just want it's return type to be same as that of the abstract class.

Comment: @KamalBanga that does avoid the shadowing, though why not just `def getA: T`?

Comment: @Imm: Ok, let me try after removing type signature in `getA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this

```
 abstract class Abs[T] {
    def getA: T
    def getA(i: T): T
  }
```

class Absz extends Abs[Int]{
    override def getA = 4
    override def getA(i: Int) = i
  }

(new Absz()).getA                               //> res0: Int = 4
  (new Absz()).getA(3)                            //> res1: Int = 3

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for understanding the question, as well as answering it. Though, what I want is not two `getA` methods. Just one will suffice. I wasn't able to figure out how to extend parameterized classes. So I just had to do `class Absz extends Abs[Int]` instead of `class Absz[Int] extends class Abs[T]`. Could you plz explain this notation, its' slightly confusing to me.

Comment: You should go through java generics tutorial(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). Its Java but the essence is same and its very detailed. Anyways,by saying Abs[T], you are creating a generic class which can support multiple types. The classes which extends Abs will define what type will Abs supports. The classes that extends Abs will have proper types and not T, so the `class Absz[Int] extends class Abs[T]` is very confusing and does not make sense :P

Answer (score 1):

With the current base method signature this is impossible since generics are erased.

Take a type tag (I also renamed the method's `T` to `U` to prevent confusion because of shadowing):

```
abstract class abs[T] {
    def getA[U: TypeTag](): U
}

class ABS[T] extends abs[T] {
    override def getA[U]()(implicit tag: TypeTag[U]): U = {
        if (tag == typeTag[Int]) new Integer(1)
        else if (tag == typeTag[Char]) new Character('1')
        else throw new Exception("bad type")
    }.asInstanceOf[U]
}
```

Comment: Hey, I wasn't able to express what I want precisely, so I just modified the question.

Comment: Please refrain from modifying questions, especially when other people have gone through the effort of providing answers. If you have a different question, ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Shapeless polymorphic functions: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0

```
import shapeless._

object Abs extends Poly0{
  implicit def caseInt = at[Int](4)
  implicit def caseChar = at[Char]('4')
}

println(Abs.apply[Int])
println(Abs.apply[Char])
```

Comment: My main motive here is to use generics in overridden methods, not to do this this some other way.

Comment: it's impossible to do it the way you tried in original question, shapeless provides workaround for the problem

Comment: I modified the question to better illustrate what exactly I want.